# jQuery, change-event ONLY when user himself changes an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

we can detect if a user changes something:

```
$('#item').change(function() { 
    alert('changed!');
});
```

sadly, sometimes I need to call it artiffically: `$('#item').change()` but in this case it is also taken as "changed". Is there a way to distinguish user actvity from manual activity?

Comment: If it's a text input, you can use the [Keypress function](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/), as follows:

`$( "#item" ).keypress(function() {
  alert('changed!');
});`

For clicky inputs, you can use click handlers:

If it's a text input, you can use the [Keypress function](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/), as follows:

`$( "#item" ).on("click", function() {
  alert('changed!');
});`

Comment: @Niek FWIW: the `keypress` event will not fire if you paste things in (either via keyboard or mouse).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The first argument returned from a jQuery event handler is the event object:

```
$('#item').change(function(e) { 
  console.log(e); // The event object
});
```

The way I usually differentiate between a user-triggered event and a code-triggered event is that user-triggered events have an `originalEvent` property attached to them. I don't know if this is the best approach, but I'd do it like this:

```
$('#item').change(function(e) { 
  if (e.originalEvent) {
    // user-triggered event
  }
  else {
    // code-triggered event
  }
});
```

---

### Example

Type in the `input` element in the below example, then unfocus the element. You'll get an alert saying `"user-triggered"`. Click the button to call a code-triggered change. You'll get an alert saying `"code-triggered"`.

```js
$('#item').change(function(e) { 
  if (e.originalEvent) {
    alert('user-triggered')
  }
  else {
    alert('code-triggered')
  }
});

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#item').change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text id=item />
<button>Click here to trigger change</button>
```

Comment: @FreddySidauruk I don't really know what you're meaning by "multilevel group user"... Are you sure you're commenting on the right question?

Comment: oke , wait i'm trying to make my english become easy to understand with you, the question about **is detect if a user** which is means there are  users with level admin, employee, etc. my question if in one time there are user with level admin and employee click, is it still working ?

Note : consider it with event click

Comment: @FreddySidauruk sorry, but that got completely nothing to do with this question or this answer. javascript is client-side code and got nothing to do with user management. so of course it works for everyone that got access to this code.

Comment: Thanks, saved my life from having to hack up the code base any further.

Answer (score 7):

A different approach from `originalEvent` should be using event params:

```
$('#item').change(function(event, who) {
    if(who === "machine")
        alert('machine!');
    else
        alert('human!');
});

$("#item").trigger("change", ["machine"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The event parameter of the callback will contain an originalEvent key when a the event is triggered by the user, so you can do:

```
    $('#item').change(function(e){
        if (e.originalEvent){
            alert('Changed by user');
        }
        // Place common code here
    });
```